# como ocultar access y solo navegar con formularios?

Tags: ms-access

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al ejecutar access hacer que mi formulario aparezca solo sin mostrar la barras de navegación

Comment: Opciones -> Base de datos actual -> Mostrar formulario: y eliges el formulario que quieras que salga al inicio.

Comment: @David, tu comentario, aunque parezca una simpleza es la respuesta correcta, ¿podrías colocar este comentario como respuesta para que sea aceptada?

Comment: @toledano ya lo he incluido, pensaba que por esa simpleza no merecía la pena poner una respuesta :) Gracias por el consejo!

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar que salga en el menú de la izquierda de la UI de Access todos los componentes (tablas, consultas, macros, módulos e informes) debes indicarle que se use un formulario como pantalla de inicio.

Para ello ve a:

```
Opciones -> Base de datos actual -> Mostrar formulario: nombre formulario a mostrar.
```